# Good Code Practice - Why does eClipse force us to use "only lower-case letters, numbers and !" for Token name?

Tags: gwt, gwtp

Ok, I am using GWTP on eclipse. When creating a Presenter using eclipse & when I enter a token name say "**!manageOrder**" then eclipse show an error that "**Token name must contain only lower-case letters, numbers and !**". See the following picture.
[image]

However, in the NameTokens class, there is a line:

```
public static final String manageorder = "!mnageorder";
```

We can change to lowercase or upper the system is still ok.

So why does eClipse force us to use "only lower-case letters, numbers and !" for Token name?

if i use "!manageOrder" then it must easier for customer to figure out the what the page is right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is just best practice being enforced by the version of the GWTP plugin you are using. It looks like you are using the old version of the plugin (for before GWTP 1.0)...

**The new plugin allows capitals in the names:**

[image]

Anyhow I would say use capitals if you want to, as long as it works.

More importantly, get using the current versions of [GWTP](https://github.com/ArcBees/GWTP/) and the associated plugin: https://github.com/ArcBees/gwtp-eclipse-plugin